# Conditional formatting in excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have table with multiple columns. On Column 'E' I want to apply conditional formatting (from Rule Manager). Based on values in column M and N, the color coding for corresponding cell in column E should change.

The problem is when I refresh the table (via macro call), I do some column insert and delete such that values in column E first shift right and then moves left. Now when the values shift to Right (column F), the formatting also shift right. However, when the values move back to column E, the formatting stays in column F (based on values of M and N).

The "Applies to" field in Rules Manager messes up. It is supposed to be "=$E$1:$E$6400" but it changes to "=$E$71:$E$6400, $F$1:$F$70" ( 70 rows have values in that table that refreshed)

How can I ensure that the formatting preserves to column E and do not shift to column F.

Comment: I suggest that you avoid shifting part of the column to the right, if you can (it's normally not the quickest way to update a worksheet).

Comment: Hi Graham, Thanks for you reply. However, this is kind of a requirement. I am inserting a column to enter values (via macro) so that  the table is worthy of just copy&paste on a report document.  I will appreciate any suggestion so that "Applies field" remains intact.

Comment: It's a little difficult for me to help you because I only have Excel 2007 or 2003. I know things changed between 2007 and 2010 with regard to splitting formatting. In 2007 if I move a block right and left, then formatting moves back again with the block, but instead of one range formatted, I have two. How do you move the _values back to column E_ ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it was asked some time ago but maybe you still having this problem ;)

To sum up a little, you are using macro that makes some changes with columns and it messes up the conditional formatting. How about add some more code to your macro - to delete conditional formatting before any actions and then add it again with columns reworked?

Adding certain code shouldn't be a problem - you can record it.